# Node.js util.inspect output clarification

Tags: node.js, output

I know there have been many questions about this topic, but I've read through them and I'm seeing output from this function that isn't mentioned.

I'm running `util.inspect` on an object:

```
util.inspect(xyz, { showHidden: true });
```

And getting output like this:

```
{ [Function: foo]
  [name]: foo,
  [arguments]: bar,
  [prototype]: 
   { foobarize: 
      { [Function: foobarize]
        [length]: 99,
        [name]:  foobarize,
        [prototype]: [Object]
      },
      [constructor]: foob
    }
 }
```

What command(s) would I need to run `foobarize()` on the object `xyz`?

Comment: Seems like no one knows...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. It was to do the following:

```
xyz.prototype.foobarize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything on an object's `prototype` is callable by instances.

```
// foo is defined
var inst_foo = new foo();
inst_foo.foobarize(); // calls foobarize() from instance
```

This is more object oriented than calling it from the blueprint function's (object definition) `prototype`.